# Proof that $f^* T=\langle ,\rangle$ for $T$ an inner product on $V$

Tags: tensors

[image]
I fail to see why $T(w_i',w_j')=0$ if $i\neq j$. I could see that $T(w_1',w_2')$ is indeed zero, but for $T(w_1',w_3')$ I don't see it very quickly, while according to Spivak it should be easy?

I did the following:
$$
T(w_1',w_3')=T\left(w_1,w_3-\dfrac{T(w_1',w_3)}{T(w_1\,w_1')}w_1'-\dfrac{T(w_2\,w_3)}{T(w_2',w_2')}w_2'\right).
$$
Using the linearity of $T$, I can see that $T(w_1,w_3')$ and $T(w_1',w_3')$ cancel, and I am left with
$$
T(w_1',w_3')=-\dfrac{T(w_2',w_3)}{T(w_2',w_2')}T(w_1',w_2').
$$
However, how is it so clear that this will yield zero as well? It seems to  me I will have to write out $w_2'$ again, but surely this cannot be the right method?

*EDIT*

So for the general case, we use induction. Say we have $T(w_i',w_j')=0$ for $i\neq j$ and all $1\leq i,j\leq n$. I now want to show that $T(w_i',w_{n+1}')=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. So we have
$$
T(w_i',w_{n+1}')=T(w_i,w_{n+1}),
$$
using the linearity of $T$ and our induction hypothesis. But how do I show that this is zero?

*EDIT2*

Well I figured it out. It's a lot to write down, but if anyone wants me to, I'll do it.

Comment: For future reference, that calculation is called [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have left to notice is that $T(w_1^\prime, w_2^\prime) = 0$. This just follows from the definitions of $w_1^\prime$, $w_2^\prime$ and the computation:

\begin{equation}
  T(w_1^\prime, w_2^\prime) = T(w_1, w_2^\prime) = T(w_1, w_2) - \frac{T(w_1, w_2)}{T(w_1, w_1)} T(w_1, w_1) = 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Fair enough, but should I use induction for the general case? I can write down (in my original post) what I have so far.

Comment: That's right, take the base case $n=1$ or $n=2$ and use induction to prove it for $n=m$.

Comment: What you have in the EDIT section is not quite correct:

\begin{equation}
  T(w_i^\prime, w_{n+1}^\prime) = T\left( w_i^\prime, w_{n+1} - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{T(w_j^\prime, w_{n+1})}{T(w_j^\prime, w_j^\prime)} w_j^\prime\right) = T(w_i^\prime, w_{n+1}) - \frac{T(w_i^\prime, w_{n+1})}{T(w_i^\prime, w_i^\prime)}T(w_i^\prime, w_i^\prime) = 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Yea the first Edit was wrong indeed. Thanks for writing it out